# Difference between $'$foo' and $"$foo"

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am having difficulties figuring out some the nuances between single and double quotes within a variable context

I define:

```
foo=pwd
```

then run these:

```
echo $'$foo'
```

Which echos `$foo` (meaning the first `$` in my echo command is dropped)

```
echo $"$foo"
```

This echos `pwd` (which means the bash expands `$foo`, my variable, to its value)

```
echo $`$foo`
```

Finally this echos `$~/scripts` (I expected it to print `~/scripts` and not `$~/scripts`)

can somebody help me figure out these differences?

Answer (score 11):

- `echo $'$foo'`: the `$'[...]'` token around `$foo` [interprets `$foo` literally (as `$foo`) and tries to expand ANSI C-like escape sequences in it](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings), which are not present, so `echo` yields `$foo`;
- `echo $"$foo"`: the `$"[...]"` token around `$foo` [expands `$foo` to its value (`pwd`) and tries to translate it if the current locale is not POSIX / C](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#i18nl10n); this is not happening, because either the current locale is POSIX / C or a translation for `pwd` is not available, so `echo` yields `pwd`;
- `` echo $`$foo` ``: the `` `[...]` `` token around `$foo` allows the expansion of `$foo`, so `$foo` is expanded to its value (`pwd`); the expanded value is run in a subshell, whose output (`~/scripts`) replaces the whole `` `[...]` `` token, so `echo` yields the `$` token followed by the `~/scripts` token (`$~/scripts`).

Ultimately, the last one prints `$~/scripts` because `` $`foo` `` is a combination of a literal `$` followed by a command substitution; so the leading `$` is interpreted as a literal `$` and the trailing `` `$foo` `` as a command substitution.

Comment: I removed the code tags and replaces with just ```````` characters etc. Feel free to rollback if you prefer the code tags

Comment: @Tim Thanks, not sure what I did exactly but for some reason after your edited the post appeared just as disrupted as in my first revision, so I rolled it back... And now I see it looks ok in the revision. Not sure what happened, gonna test this in the formatting sandbox before rolling back to your version since I fear I might disrupt the post again. Regardless, thanks for the effort.

Comment: sure, no issues. Mine uses zero-width spaces, so be careful as you edit.

Answer (score 2):

First case:

> ```
> echo $'$foo'
> ```
>
> Which echos `$foo` (meaning the first `$` in my echo command is dropped)

The first `$` is run as a command. Echo doesn't require spaces between arguments, it just takes them.

So echo `$'$foo'` expands to run the command `$` (which isn't a command so it ignores it) and then echo `'$foo'`. Anything in `''` is taken at face value - it doesn't expand it or anything. You can put what you want in '' and nothing happens.

If you replace the `$` with `$$` it echos the process ID.

---

Second:

> ```
> echo $"$foo"
> ```
>
> This echos `pwd` (which means the bash expands `$foo`, my variable, to its value)

That's because `""` doesn't prevent it expanding. `""` is normally used to ensure there is a value to compare to.

If you have a variable that could be empty (e.g. it is from a `grep` result) then you want to compare to another value / variable, you have to put the first variable in `""`. This ensures that there is always a comparison to check, rather than just an empty section of code (as bash sees) which gives an error.

---

Finally, number 3. This is interesting.

> ```
> echo $`$foo`
> ```
>
> This echos `$~/scripts` (I expected it to print `~/scripts` and not `$~/scripts`)

That's because (in this case) echo is printing the `$` character first. Putting something in backticks causes *the value of the variable to be run as a command* (the better way to do it in more recent versions of bash is `$(command)`)

So first it echos `$` then it expands `` ​`$foo`​ `` to `` ​`pwd`​ `` which is run and returns `~/Scripts`. But we had the `$` print earlier - so the whole output is `$~/Scripts`.

Comment: Nice work on some very difficult formatting!

Comment: @Arronical Thanks :) You can't see it but there are some zero-width spaces there for the last sentence. The things I do for imaginary internet points...!

Comment: +1 Good answer. I would just add that quoting variables should be the default unless you have a specific reason not to - not just to handle possible null values. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells for more than you ever wanted to know about this. ;)