# Bash script to get the variable expansion within a section of code that requires single quotes around it

Tags: network-monitoring

I have a command (snmptrap) that requires input strings to be in single quotes.   Within a bash script, run this command which I need to insert a variable and expand it.
I have tried numerous variation but to no avail.  I have also search several web sites to find a similar situation, but no help.

```
DT=`date '+%a %b %d, %Y at %H:%M:%S'`

Dev="1#.##.##.147"  

DESTINATION=$Dev

VAR3="DATA_TRANSFER_NAVISTOR - EBR -test "$DT" - ERRORLEVEL 111."

/usr/bin/snmptrap -v 1 -c public $DESTINATION 1.3.6.1.4.1.791 10.36.1.177 6 200 '' \
.1.3.6.1.4.1.791.200.1  s 'NS_Monitor' \
.1.3.6.1.4.1.791.200.2  s 'NAVISTOR' \
.1.3.6.1.4.1.791.200.3  s '\"$VAR3\"' \
.1.3.6.1.4.1.791.200.4  s 'CRITICAL' \
.1.3.6.1.4.1.791.200.5  s 'hostname=na900618-sal.delhaize.com'

$VAR3  
$[$VAR3]    
"$VAR3"  
\$VAR3   
\"$VAR3\"
```

Comment: The variable that will not expand is in the line:  .1.3.6.1.4.1.791.200.3 s '"$VAR3"'

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what you mean by *"a section of code that requires single quotes around it"* - the single quotes around command arguments like `snmptrap ... 'NAVISTOR'` are removed by the shell before the `NAVISTOR` argument is passed to the command

Comment: There may be a better duplicate for this, but based on your answer it sounds like this *might* answer your original question -- [Difference between $'$foo' and $"$foo"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736226/difference-between-foo-and-foo)

Answer (score 0):

A colleague said to simply replace the single quotes with double quotes so that the var3 line is:  .1.3.6.1.4.1.791.200.3 s "$VAR3" \

This works.

Comment: You should probably understand the difference between single and double quotes in Bash. Double qoutes expand variables, single qoutes do not.